# How to get persian address

Tags: java, android, google-maps-api-3, google-geocoder

**Hello world!**

I'm trying to develop a app which it shows persian addresses based on latitude and longitude.
How should I implement this ?

I use GeoCoder class this way;

```
 public String  getAddress(Context context ,double latitude , double longitude)
 {
    String fullAddress = null ;
    try {
        Geocoder geocode = new Geocoder(context, new Locale("fa"));
        List<android.location.Address> addresses = geocode.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
        Address ad = addresses.get(0);
        fullAddress = ad.getAddressLine(0);
    }
    catch (IOException exc)
    {
        fullAddress =exc.getMessage();
        exc.printStackTrace();
    }

    return fullAddress;
}
```

And here is what I get.

```
 W/System.err: java.io.IOException: grpc failed
 W/System.err:     at android.location.Geocoder.getFromLocation(Geocoder.java:136)
```

The result doesn't change if I send Locale.getDefault() as Geocoder Ctor param

What is wrong with this piece of code ?

**THANKS FOR YOUR ANSWERS**

Answer (score 0):

There is a possiblty that you get this from `getFromLocation` method that returned empty list as referred [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder) but I solved same problem by doing things below.

1. If you had this problem prior to this post, re-run your app and see
   if it works now.
2. If it still doesn't work try to uninstall and delete all files
       related to Android Studio. (NOT the project files).
3. Then reinstall Android Studio, and reopen the project back up.
4. When running the app use a different virtual device and device API.